# Arithmetic error in C function

Tags: c

```
int getTempo()
{
    int tempo;
    //User can enter tempo in bpm
    tempo = (aserveGetControl(07) / 127) * 250;
    //equation to convert tempo in bpm to an integer in ms to use with aserveSleep
    return ((1000/tempo) * 60);

}
```

program won't run past this function, get the following error: 
Thread 1:EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)

Comment: What is the value of `tempo`? Is it zero?

Comment: Paste in the function `aserveGetControl()`. Seems like it might come back with something less than 127.

Comment: If `aserveGetControl(07)` returns a value less than `127` your result will be zero. It's highly doubtful you will get the results you want with integer operations, try change to use floating point values instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use integer maths, you should do the multiplication(s) *before* division(s).

**Example 1 (truncation to zero)**

```
  (100 / 127) * 250
= (0) * 250
= 0
```

On the other hand

```
  (100 * 256) / 127
= 25600 / 127
= 201
```

**Example 2 (loss of precision)**

```
  (1000 / 27) * 60
= (370) * 60
= 2220
```

On the other hand

```
  (1000 * 60) / 27
= (60000) / 127
= 2222
```

Try this:

```
int getTempo()
{
    int tempo;
    //User can enter tempo in bpm
    tempo = (aserveGetControl(07) * 250) / 127;

    //equation to convert tempo in bpm to an integer in ms to use with aserveSleep
    return (60 * 1000) / tempo ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If, as I suppose, `aserveGetControl` returns an integer between 0 and 127, `tempo` will always be zero (unless `aserveGetControl` returns exactly 127), since you are performing an integer division, which truncates the result to the integer part. You should invert the division and the multiplication in both your expressions, and be ready anyway to deal with the fact that `aserveGetcontrol` may return 0.

Comment: Thanks, what should the expressions be?

Comment: @FUZxxl: not necessarily, if both the input and output are integers you can just move all the multiplications before and do a single division at the end (of course you must be careful to avoid overflows).